# Add product thumbnail in order email template

Tags: magento2, order-email

> I want to add product thumbnail and custom attribute in the order
>   email template.

Help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml
>   file to your custom module
>   Company\Helloworld\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_email_item_price"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="items" template="Company_Helloworld::email/items.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="2"</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode">
                        <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create custom module and create one custom Block as below

> Company\Helloworld\Block\Example.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Helloworld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Example extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    ){
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
    }

    public function getProduct($productId)
    {
        return  $this->_productModel->load($productId);
    }


}
```

> then above block method we can call in
>   Company\Helloworld\view\frontend\templates\email\items.phtml
>
> override
>   \vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items.phtml
>   to your custom module
>   Company\Helloworld\view\frontend\templates\email\items.phtml

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile


    $blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Helloworld\Block\Example');

    ?>


    <?php $_order = $block->getOrder();
      $oriderId = $_order->getEntityId();
     ?>
    <?php if ($_order): ?>
        <?php $_items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 25%">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Sku') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty') ?>
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal') ?>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           <?php   
           foreach ($_items as $_item):
           ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php   

                        $productId = $_item->getProductId();
                        $product = $blockObj->getProduct($productId); // your product object here
                        $productImgUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                            ->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')
                            ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                            ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                            ->resize(90, 110)->getUrl();
                        ?>
                                <td><img src= "<?php echo $productImgUrl;?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $product->getName();?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo intval($_item->getQtyOrdered());?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $currency; echo number_format($_item->getRowTotal(), 2, '.', '');?></td>
                                <?php // $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                    </tr>

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
        </table>


         <tfoot class="order-totals">
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
         </tfoot>



        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
            <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
            <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
                <br />
                <table class="message-gift">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                            <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                            <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                            <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                            <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I will update you. Thanks!

Comment: This is a terrible way of achieving this, the answer from Adam is substantially better

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is a very hacky way to achieve what you want and I wouldn't recommend it.

If you override the file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` you can add the thumbnail easily enough, since you have access to the full product model, as well as your custom attributes:

```php
/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem(); // core magento code

// ...
/** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null */
$product = $_item->getProduct();
?>

Thumbnail URL path: <?= /** @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getData('thumbnail') ?? 'no thumbnail'; ?>
My Custom Attribute: <?= /** @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getData('custom_attribute_name'); ?>
```

Since the underlying code of `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item::getProduct()` calls `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::load($id)` you should be able to grab your custom attributes this way.

If you need to resize the product image, the helper method is an appropriate way of doing it like Hitesh suggests:

```php
// same code as before
$fullImageUrl = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'my_product_image_thumbnail_id')->/* other params */->resize(100,100)->getUrl();
```